# Reformat .csv in python: count commas in a row and insert line break after specific number of commas

Tags: python, csv, count

I'm new to python and looking for a script that reformats a .csv file. So in my .csv files there are rows which are not formatted correctly. It does look similar to this:

```
id,author,text,date,id,author,
text,date
id,author,text,date
id,author,text,date
```

It's supposed to have "id,author,text,date" on each line. So my idea was to count the commas in each row and when a specific number is achieved (in this example 4) it will insert the remainder at the beginning of the next row. What I got is the following which counts the commas in one row:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f) # create rows split on commas
    for row in r:
        com_count = 0
        com_count += len(row)
        print(com_count)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did you end up with such a scrambled csv file? Is there a way to maybe export it again without these format errors?

Comment: How large is the file? I mean, can you read the entire file at once?

Answer (score 0):

We're going to build a generator that yields entries and then build the new rows from that

```
with open('oldfile.csv', newline='') as old:
    r = csv.reader(old)
    num_cols = int(input("How many columns: "))
    entry_generator = (entry for row in r for entry in row)
    with open('newfile.csv', 'w+', newline='') as newfile:
        w = csv.writer(newfile)
        while True:
            try:
                w.writerow([next(entry_generator) for _ in range(num_cols)])
            except StopIteration:
                break
```

This will not work if you have a row that is missing entries.

If you want to handle getting the column width programmatically, you can either wrap this in a function that takes a width as input, or use the first row of the csv as a canonical length